# SQL to MDX Where IN clause

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a situation where I need to formulate an MDX query.The corresponding `SQL` query would look something like:

```
SELECT no_of_downloads 
FROM   table_1
WHERE  project_code IN ('abc', 'def', 'ghi' , .....)
```

I have the following MDX query formulated but i can only use it for one project code at a time.

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[#Activity] ON COLUMNS
 ,Filter
  (
    [Organisation Dimension].[Txt Project Code].MEMBERS
   ,
    [Organisation Dimension].[Txt Project Code].CurrentMember.Name = 'KM_BNG'
  ) ON ROWS
FROM [Activity Cube]
WHERE 
  (
    [Activity Dimension].[Txt Activity Name].&[Download]
   ,[System Dimension].[Txt System Name].&[KShop] //ENTER CODE HERE//
   ,[Time Dimension].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Half Year Name].&[2014-04-01T00:00:00]
  );
```

How to add more project codes in the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or if you're really keen to use the `WHERE` clause then just move the `SET` created by FrankPI into the `WHERE` clause.

The `WHERE`clause is conceptually an axis and as a rule of `MDX` is that the same hierarchy cannot be placed on more than one axis you will need to move it from `ROWS` like this:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[#Activity] ON 0
FROM [Activity Cube]
WHERE 
  (
    [Activity Dimension].[Txt Activity Name].&[Download]
   ,[System Dimension].[Txt System Name].&[KShop]
   ,{
       [Organisation Dimension].[Txt Project Code].[KM_BNG],
       [Organisation Dimension].[Txt Project Code].[other name],
       [Organisation Dimension].[Txt Project Code].[third name]
    }
   ,[Time Dimension].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Half Year Name].&[2014-04-01T00:00:00]
  );
```

In the extreme case where you have 50 members of the hierarchy `[Organisation Dimension].[Txt Project Code]` that you want to include then it might be better managed in the cube script. You could create a set [myTxtProjectCodes] and then the `MDX` would be a lot simpler:

```
SELECT 
  [Measures].[#Activity] ON 0
FROM [Activity Cube]
WHERE 
  (
    [Activity Dimension].[Txt Activity Name].&[Download]
   ,[System Dimension].[Txt System Name].&[KShop]
   ,{
       [myTxtProjectCodes]
    }
   ,[Time Dimension].[Fiscal Hierarchy].[Fiscal Half Year Name].&[2014-04-01T00:00:00]
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer.My qstn basically was,that in an sql query,inside the brackets of WHERE projectCode IN(),we can potentially copy paste any number of project codes as long as they are inside single quotes and separated by a comma.In an extreme case,where i need data of say 50 project codes,i get the list of proj. codes from another query,comma/colon separate it using FIND AND REPLACE,and paste it.I was wondering if there were any similar way to do it in MDX.Otherwise,for 50 project codes,i'd hv to paste the code at the end of each slicer like [Organisation Dimension].[Txt Project Code].xyz

Comment: you could create a set inside the cube. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need filters, you just can enumerate the members in the `ON ROWS` clause in curly braces:

```
SELECT [Measures].[#Activity]
       ON COLUMNS ,
       {
       [Organisation Dimension].[Txt Project Code].[KM_BNG],
       [Organisation Dimension].[Txt Project Code].[other name],
       [Organisation Dimension].[Txt Project Code].[third name]
       }
       ON ROWS
...
```

Comment: but what if there are more than 50 of them? Is there any way i can just write them in a list like we can do in the IN clause in sql?

Comment: @user3678795 I do not understand your question. What I put into my answer **is** a list of members.